# How to view contents from the database using snapshot firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, snapshot

[image: Json Code]

[image: Database]

```
      package com.example.durveshshah.feedback;

       import android.app.ProgressDialog;
      import android.content.Intent;
       import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
      import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
       import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.util.Log;
     import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
      import android.widget.EditText;
      import android.widget.ListView;
       import android.widget.Toast;

        import com.firebase.client.Firebase;
        import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
        import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
        import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
        import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
        import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
        import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
         import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
       import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
        import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
        import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

        import java.util.ArrayList;

       public class Main4Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "viewDatabase";
    private DatabaseReference mRef;
    private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
    private String UserId;
    private ListView mListView;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main4);

    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference();
    final FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    UserId = user.getUid();

    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if(user!=null)
            {
                //User is signed in
                Log.d(TAG,"onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:"+ user.getUid());
                Log.d(TAG,"onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:"+ user.getEmail());
            }
            else
            {
                //User is signed out
                Log.d(TAG,"onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
            }
        }
    };


    mRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {


                    //Log.i("phone",ds.getKey());
                    ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>();
                    array.add(String.valueOf(ds.getValue()));

                    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(Main4Activity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);
                    mListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);


            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError)
        {
            Toast.makeText(Main4Activity.this,"Logged Out",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });



      }


  }
```

I have used signinwithemailandpassword inbuilt firebase mechanism in a different activity and after signing in I want to view contents of that particular user. Instead all the database contents are visible in every user I log in to.

Comment: Please add your firebase database structure and which data you want to retrieve?

Comment: This is the only structure

Comment: I want to show data in this activity

Comment: Your Firebase data base. This is only the code. You can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in your Firebase Database console.

Comment: See i have edited the description and the code. Can you understand it now. If yes please help its urgent. if anything else is needed let me know

Comment: I stll canoot see your database structure.

Comment: The only way in which i can solve this, is trough stackoverflow website. So please be as much as clear as you can.

Comment: I've uploaded my database image and json code file. Now my problem is whichever user i sign in with is able to to view the database. i've signed in with email and password using firebase inbuilt mechanism. The user should view only their contents of the database.

Comment: In short i want to retrieve the data only for that particular user who has saved it in database. Users can only see their data on the app, not everyone's data.

Comment: I'll write you the answer in a few minutes.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: It looks like you were [begging on your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/43145232/revisions), and having been notified that making demands of volunteers in unacceptable, here you are doing the same again. How can we encourage you to desist?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you need to create a new node named `users`. Every time a users signs in, you can get the `uid`. Your database should look like this:

```
Firebase-root
   |
   ---- users
          |
          ---- uid1
          |     |
          |     // details
          |
          ---- uid2
          |     |
          |     // details
          |
          ---- //and so on
```

Assuming that your phone node is nested under the `uid`, you can use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference yourRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(user.getUid()).child("phone");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String phone = ds.getValue(String.class);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
yourRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex. Did some modifications with the help of your code and got it finally

Comment: Appreciate it. Thank you